# Crear un cuadrado usando opencv en python en un objeto amorfo como una pllanta

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cv2

estoy realizando un proyecto donde pretendo obtener el tamaño de una planta por medio de una imagen, es decir busco encontrar el valor de la vertical del punto mas bajo de la planta al mas alto y evaluar su altura. Llevo semanas con un problema y es el siguiente no puedo crear el cuadrado mas cercano a los contornos en la imagen de una planta. adjunto el codigo que estoy usando asi como imagenes si es que pueden alguien orientarme en este aspecto.
Dentro del codigo se mostrara la mayor parte de lo que se hace junto con el preprocesamiento y asi eliminar el ruido alrededor de la imagen, un detalle mas esta en que no consigo formar el cuadrado mas cercano a los contornos para que de esta forma consiga obtener el tamaño de la planta

```
import cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Escoger imagen
#imagen0 = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("IMAGE files", "*.JPEG"), ("All files", "*.*")))

# leer y redimensionar el tamaño de la imagen
imagen = cv.imread("WhatsApp Image 2019-05-09 at 4.27.03 PM.jpeg") #Aqui se pone la ruta de la imagen que va a ser leida
#imagen = cv.imread(imagen0)
#imagen = cv.resize(imagen,(1200,1200))

#  cambio de escala de color rgb a hsv
hsv = cv.cvtColor(imagen, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# rango de valores de tonos verdes
verde_bajos = np.array([30, 30, 30])  # Valores perfectos para el reconocimiento de una planta[30,50,50]
verde_altos = np.array([80, 255, 255])  # valores perfectos para el reconocimiento de una planta[90,255,255])

# Usar la mascara
mascara_verde = cv.inRange(hsv, verde_bajos, verde_altos)
mask = cv.add(mascara_verde, mascara_verde)


#filtro = cv.bitwise_and(imagen, imagen, mask=mask)

# condicion del filtro por vencindades
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)


# Transformacion morfologica de apertura
contornos = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
contornos = cv.erode(contornos,kernel,iterations = 1)
contornos = cv.dilate(contornos,kernel,iterations = 1)
# Colocacion de la mascara

# suavido gausiano y recuperacion de contornos
#contornos = cv.cvtColor(contornos,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#contornos = cv.GaussianBlur(apertura, (5, 5), 3)

# Umbralizado
ret, tresh = cv.threshold(contornos, 1, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_TRIANGLE)
# Recuperacion de contornos
ds,bordes = cv.findContours(tresh, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# aqui se dibujan los contornos
#cv.drawContours(imagen, bordes, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv.LINE_AA)

for c in ds:
    area = cv.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100 and area < 1000:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(c)
        cv.rectangle(imagen, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (-1, 255, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)

#for c in bordes:

# diferencia entre lo recuperado y el resto y asi mostrar en pantalla la segmentacion

filtro1 = cv.bitwise_and(imagen, imagen, mask=contornos)

# def para poder mostrar en pantalla resultados

cv.imshow('Inicial', filtro1)
cv.imshow('Limpia', contornos)
#cv.imshow(('cuadrado',nuevo))

#
while (1):
    tecla = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if tecla == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: imagen de la planta]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función RETR_EXTERNAL de findContours.

Imagen de resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo mi código de ejemplo:

```
import cv2 as cv 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

imagen = cv.imread("imagenes/planta.jpg") 
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(imagen, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, tresh = cv.threshold(img_gray, 240, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV )

kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
mask = cv.morphologyEx(tresh, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
mask = cv.morphologyEx(tresh, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

major = cv.__version__.split('.')[0]
if major == '3':
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
else:
    contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

imgray = cv.cvtColor(img_gray,cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

for c in contours:
    area = cv.contourArea(c)
    if (area > 1000 and area < 13000):
        x,y,w,h = cv.boundingRect(c)
        cv.rectangle(imgray,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

cv.imshow('imgray', imgray)
#
while (1):
    tecla = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if tecla == 27:
        break
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```